# Load a web page in web view with some pre-initialize data on that web page

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on a application which uses both native android as well as webview for some of the pages. Like login is in native but the user profile is in webview. 
Web pages are designed in such a way that if session id and other info available session storage, cookies or a javascript variable, it will work seamlessly.

If i login using the native and pass that session id to the webpage javascript variable every thing will work as expected. But I am not sure if i can do that.

Is there any way to init the javascript variables before loading the page?
Or any better solution for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the data as GET parameters in your URL and then grab those parameters with JavaScript.

Once the pages got loaded prefill the necessary fields with the parameters you just got from URL.

For example assuming that there are two input fields needed to be filled in the page with id `username` & `email` you would set the webview URL to `http://mypagedomain.com?username=awesome&email=awesome@mail.com`

Then you could use JavaScript on page load to retrieve this parameters utilizing `window.location.href` or `window.location.search`

Comment: Hmmm...sounds more like what I need..Can I post that data to any url too?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You can send these data to any URL but you will have to use GET method. That means these data have to be part of the URL like so: 
http://mypagedomain.com?sessionid=somesessionidalreadyknowntoandroid

Comment: Yes I can..found a link..http://glorious-arvind.blogspot.in/2012/11/webview-posturl-postdata.html

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, you need to run a custom `javascript` in your `WebView`.
To do that:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript: toBeCalledFromAndroid('test')");
```

Comment: @KumarRanjan, `Is there any way to init the javascript variables before loading the page?` - that's how you can do it

Comment: that variable is define on the JS of that page which i am going to load

Comment: @KumarRanjan, you can load pre-loaded HTML code into WebView. So you get the HTML code into String first, then edit the value you need, and then load HTML into WebView